# Getting number of views of a song, Spotify API

Tags: spotify

Has anyone managed to retrieve the number of views for a song on Spotify? This information is available for songs via the desktop app, but I am looking for an autonomous solution. I'm currently experimenting with the Spotify Api and was wondering if anyone has had better luck

Answer (score 1):

This information isn't available through the Web API, all they offer instead is the [popularity of a track](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/tracks/get-track/), which is a value 0-100 generated from some function of total number of listens over time.

I also had a look on `open.spotify.com` to see if there's any way that it would be possible to scrape the data and they don't even serve the number of listens for songs on Artist, Album pages, any more.

I think the only way it would be doable now is to extract the information from the Desktop App interface somehow.